# Easy Way to Retrieve Github Repo Information

Tags: curl, github, web, portfolio

I am working on my portfolio website, and I was thinking that it would be great if you could see the repositories that I have on my Github account on a page on the website. I don't want to perform any operations on the repo, just display its title, description, etc. I don't know anything about using cURL, so I am kind of new to the whole API thing. Any advice for starting? Is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: Please edit your question and  mention language you want to achieve this task so can give advice for starting.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can get repos by nickpalmer789 user.

visit https://api.github.com/users/nickpalmer789/repos

Give request to this url and then parse the json, you can get name and description as well.

Note: cURL is just command line tool to interact with HTTP/TCP protocols.

Comment: How would I parse the json? I am totally new to json and cURL.

Comment: @NickP please ask new question about parsing json after getting data from api because your question almost got answered.

Answer (score 0):

+Nick P, you probably will have figured out what you are looking for by now, but for anyone who still has some issues regarding parsing the `repo JSON dump` here's a quick solution in Node.js

Grab the all info about your repos using the GitHUb API and wget

`wget https://api.github.com/users/{yourGitHubUsername}/repos`

Rename the file to `repos.json` then run use the script below to get each repo's name and description

```
const fs = require('fs');

var RepoObj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('repos.json').toString());
for (var i in RepoObj) {
    console.log(RepoObj[i].name, RepoObj[i].description + '\n');
}
```

Hope this helps :)